# selenium headlessly run on server over SSH

Tags: python, user-interface, selenium, web-crawler

I am now developing a webpage crawler, unfortunately the website generates the results by ajax. Following some coders suggestion, I tried to use selenium, a test automation tool for python.
As the [example](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#chapter03-reference) given in the documentation:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

This code executes to open the Firefox browser. And then do something just like filling the form, submitting and so on.

Frankly speaking, this example works well on my PC(ubuntu 12.10), but my project will finally transfer to a CentOS server.

What I am considering is whether the code(need to open a browser gui) can be successfully ran on the CentOS server over ssh because no KDE such as gnome provided on that machine.....

And if without browser gui, the code cannot work well, then is there any other solutions?

Any reply would be admired~

Comment: have a look at http://phantomjs.org/, it is a headless browser. I currently use it in conjunction with selenium on a server with no GUI

Answer (score 0):

You can *probably* use the [HtmlUnit driver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver) if you enable javascript.  The only way to be sure though is to test it out.  Another option would be to try and run with an X framebuffer.